# Parallel function call in php

Tags: php, parallel-processing, swoole, amphp, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

Is there a way to execute internal functions in parallel in PHP?

For example, I have four functions:

```
function a(){
    return 1;
}

function b(){
    return 2;
}

function c(){
    return 3;
}

function d(){
    return 4;
}
```

When I call these functions sequentially like this:

```
function E(){
    $response = [] ;
    $response['a'] = a();
    $response['b'] = b();
    $response['c'] = c();
    $response['d'] = d();
}
```

They execute in sequential order. However, I want to call them in parallel. Is there any way to achieve this in PHP?

I tried with AMP and swoole php but not worked

Comment: PHP doesn't support task-based asynchronous programming, no.

Comment: Short answer: no, but if you really need to run things in parallel and don't mind taking on the overhead of managing multiple PHP processes, you can do something similar. You can fork separate processes either using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php or your operating systems process control via https://www.php.net/exec.  Bear in mind these will fork full PHP processes though, and it will be up to you to collect outputs using some kind of inter-process communication.  There are libraries and framework components that can help you, depending on what you might be using.

Comment: Swoole, pcntl and amp all can do this. `Does not work` is not a proper description. Show examples and we may assist you.

Comment: @jimsmith Javascript has no parallelism, but async workflow. It looks similar, but is clearly not the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Executing functions in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684290/executing-functions-in-parallel)

Comment: I used this code but in this one also it is not parallel execute 

`use Amp\Loop;
use Amp\Promise;
function internalFunction1() {
    return \Amp\call(function () {
        yield \Amp\delay(9000); seconds
        return 'Result from Internal Function 1';
    });
}
function internalFunction2() {
    return \Amp\call(function () {
        yield \Amp\delay(0); 
        return 'Result from Internal Function 2';
    });
}
Loop::run(function () {
    $results = yield Promise\all([
        internalFunction1(),
        internalFunction2(),
    ]);
    print_r($results);
});
`

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

Answer (score 1):

Swoole can do this. Does not work is not a proper description.

Mutliple corotuines created with go are executed concurrently.

```php
<?php
co::run(function() {
    go(function () {
        co::sleep(3);
        go(function () {
            co::sleep(2);
            echo "co[3] end\n";
        });
        echo "co[2] end\n";
    });

    co::sleep(1);
    echo "co[1] end\n";
});
```

```php
<?php

use Swoole\Coroutine;

function a()
{
    echo 1;
    sleep(1);
    echo __FUNCTION__;
}

function b()
{
    echo 2;
    sleep(1);
    echo __FUNCTION__;
}

function c()
{
    echo 3;
    sleep(1);
    echo __FUNCTION__;
}

function d()
{
    echo 4;
    sleep(1);
    echo __FUNCTION__;
}

Coroutine\run(function () {
    Coroutine::create('a');
    Coroutine::create('b');
    Coroutine::create('c');
    Coroutine::create('d');
});
```

learn more https://openswoole.com/docs/modules/swoole-coroutine-create

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it